# Sorting data with some similar words in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a database with 100 columns, but a minimal production of my data are as follows:

```html
df1<=read.table(text="PG1S1AW KOM1S1zo PG2S2AW KOM2S2zo PG3S3AW KOM3S3zo PG4S4AW KOM4S4zo PG5S5AW KOM5S5zo
4 1 2 4 4 3 0 4 0 5
4 4 3 1 3 1 0 3 0 1
2 3 5 3 3 2 1 4 0 2
1 1 1 1 1 3 0 5 0 1
2 5 3 4 4 5 0 1 3 4", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get columns starting with KOM and PG which have a greater of 3 . So we need to have PG4, KOM4 and above. Put it simply, starting with PG and KOM have the same values which is 4 and greater.
The intended output is:

```html
PG4S4AW KOM4S4zo PG5S5AW KOM5S5zo
0 4 0 5
0 3 0 1
1 4 0 2
0 5 0 1
0 1 3 4
```

I have used the following code, but it does not work for me:

```html
df2<- df1%>% select(contains("KO"))
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear about the patterns.  We create a function (`f1`) to extract one or more digits (`\\d+`) that follows the 'KOM' or (`|`) 'PG' with `str_extract`  (from `stringr`), convert to numeric ('v1'), similarly, extract numbers after the 'S' ('v2').  Do a check whether these values are same and if one of the value is greater than 3, wrap  with `which`  so  that if there are any NAs resulting from `str_extract` would be removed as `which` gives the column index while removing any NAs.  Use the function in `select` to select  the columns that follow the pattern

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
f1 <- function(nm) {
  v1 <- as.numeric(str_extract(nm, "(?<=(KOM|PG))\\d+"))
  v2 <- as.numeric(str_extract(nm, "(?<=S)\\d+"))
   nm[which((v1 == v2) & (v1 > 3))]
 }

df1 %>%
     select(f1(names(.)))
#   PG4S4AW KOM4S4zo PG5S5AW KOM5S5zo
#1       0        4       0        5
#2       0        3       0        1
#3       1        4       0        2
#4       0        5       0        1
#5       0        1       3        4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(PG1S1AW = c(4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L), KOM1S1zo = c(1L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 5L), PG2S2AW = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L), KOM2S2zo = c(4L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L), PG3S3AW = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L), KOM3S3zo = c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), PG4S4AW = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), KOM4S4zo = c(4L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), PG5S5AW = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L), KOM5S5zo = c(5L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your example data, you can just instead look for the numbers 4 or 5.

```r
df1 %>% 
  select(matches("4|5"))
#>   KO4S4AW KOM4S4zo KO5S5AW KOM5S5zo
#> 1       0        4       0        5
#> 2       0        3       0        1
#> 3       1        4       0        2
#> 4       0        5       0        1
#> 5       0        1       3        4
```